# ImportError: cannot import name dump_age

Tags: python

when i run my odoo8 project it shows the error,
`ImportError: cannot import name dump_age`

```
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/home/zindesk01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .common_descriptors import CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin
  File "/home/zindesk01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/common_descriptors.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..http import dump_age
ImportError: cannot import name dump_age
```

Comment: Please show us your folder structure. We aren't mind readers, we don't know where your `dump_age` nor `http` are. Please also show all imports at the top of the files causing this.

Comment: Try to provide more info like the versions of the libraries that you are using (i.e the output of `pip list`) and include the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: add more information

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently. The reason was that I somehow had installed two versions of Werkzeug: Both 0.11 (pre-0.13) and 0.16 (post-0.13). Needless to say, I was surprised this was even possible.

I uninstalled both, reinstalled the newer one, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`dump_age` was created to address this issue: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/408, It looks like it made it into version 0.13+. Generally this error means you have an old version of Werkzeug floating around (e.g. I've seen this on Centos Machines where yum was used to install python-werkzeug). Check that your version is the newest by viewing the `__version__` variable in `werkzeug/__init__.py`.